# @Composable in a overridden method?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, composable

I would like to draw a @Composable on a override method, like

```
@Composable
override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
    Greeting()
}
```

Unfortunately, I can not mark a `override onKeyDown()` with @Composable, since I get:

> Conflicting overloads: @Composable public open fun onKeyDown(keyCode:
> Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean defined in
> com.example.emptycompose.MainActivity, public open fun onKeyDown(p0:
> Int, p1: KeyEvent!): Boolean defined in
> androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

How can I use a `@Composable` in e.g. a `override onKeyDown()`?

Comment: I think that you need to have `onKeyDown()` update state that is used by your composables defined elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happen when you rename your .kt file.

For example, I rename KKbutton.kt to KKButton.kt and this error happen.

Clean and rebuild fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly return an instance of a composable like that, but you can have a composable that observes changes and recomposes automatically.

In your `ViewModel` create a `MutableLiveData` that holds the slider position.

```
    val sliderPosition = MutableLiveData<Integer>()
```

In your `Activity`, have onKeyDown update the `MutableLiveData`:

```
override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
    when (event?.keyCode) {
        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN -> {
            viewModel.sliderPosition.value = getCurrentSliderPosition()
        }
    }
}
```

Then pass the `ViewModel` as a parameter to your composable function and then you can observe volume changes like this:

```
   val position by viewModel.sliderPosition.observeAsState(0)
```

Now you can just use `position` as a regular variable in your layout, but when it changes, the `Composable` will be automatically updated with the new value.

You can read more on managing state with Compose [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state).

As a side note, there is an experimental (at the time of the answer) `keyInputFilter` `Modifier` you may want to [check out](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/input/key/package-summary).

Comment: observeAsState() is not available

Comment: @EdnaKrabappel it's an extension method of LiveData. Try adding the following imports:
`import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue` and 
`import androidx.compose.runtime.livedata.observeAsState`

Comment: @AbdelilahElAissaoui Still not visible. Compose is red

Comment: Because you can't mark that method as a Composable. Rick's answer explains it.

Answer (score 0):

`@Composable` can only be applied to an overriding function if the base function also has a `@Composable` annotation.

Whilst I'm pretty sure the provided example wouldn't work in the first place since it's an event listener (it won't be invoked in a `@Composable` context!), if you did have control over where the function is invoked, you could simply add the annotation:

```kotlin
interface Foo {
    @Composable // add this
    fun foo(): Unit
}

object Bar : Foo {
    @Composable // no error
    override fun foo(): Unit {
        Text("world, hello")
    }
}
```